# Firefox directs me to strange chinese error page, is my security compromised?

Tags: spoofing, system-compromise

Today I was working on a project on my localhost ( I'm a web developer ), when I noticed Firefox is showing a message that means I need to login to my ISP before I can start browsing ( The notification bar that appears under the address bar ). This notification leads to a URL on the Firefox's website:

> http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt

Which I think it outputs `success` if you can successfully open the URL.

But this time, after I clicked the link, the content of the page was strange, and in Chinese. Here's what I got:

> 抱歉！该网站可能由于以下原因无法访问！
>
> 1、您访问的域名未绑定至主机；
>
> 解决方法：需要网站管理员登录万网主机控制面板绑定域名，阿里云账号请登录阿里云虚拟主机控制台绑定。
>
> 2、您正在使用IP访问；
>
> 解决方法：请尝试使用域名进行访问。
>
> 3、该站点已被网站管理员停止；
>
> 解决方法：需要网站管理员登录万网主机控制面板开启站点，阿里云账号请登录阿里云虚拟主机控制台进行开通。

The translation by Google translator is:

> Sorry! This site may not be accessible due to the following reasons!
>
> 1. The domain name you visited is not bound to the host.
>
> Solution: The webmaster needs to log in to the host computer control
>   panel to bind the domain name. Alibaba Cloud account should be logged
>   in to the Alibaba Cloud virtual host console.
>
> 2. You are using IP access;
>
> Solution: Try using a domain name for access.
>
> 3. The site has been stopped by the webmaster;
>
> Solution: The webmaster needs to log in to the host control panel to
>   open the site. Alibaba Cloud account should be logged in to the
>   Alibaba Cloud virtual host console for activation.

This page also includes some links that lead to the `cp.aliyun.com` website, which I'm not familiar with. If I open the link ( first link on my question ) using a VPN, it behaves as expected.

The spooky thing is, the page contains images that do not exist on the firefox.com, this leads the images on the page being shown as blank.

Is my network compromised? Or is the Firefox website hacked? I'm not sure what's going on here, since this page never output something like this before.

I'm using the latest version of Linux Mint (updated too)

Comment: What addons do you have installed in Firefox?

Comment: Nothing. This is a clean installation of Linux Mint, I've only installed LAMP on the system, with no add-on or other program installed.

Comment: Does any other device on the network have the same issue? If yes, your router has most likely been tampered with in some way.